# asp.net mvc wcf error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am work working on asp.net wcf project. I have this error while trying to render a view.
[WCF Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2LRY.png)

**My Controller**

```
       public ActionResult Index()  
    {
        AdminService.AdminServiceClient adminsvc = new AdminService.AdminServiceClient();
        List<COUNTRIES> lstRecord = new List<COUNTRIES>();  

        var lst = adminsvc.GetAllCountries();  

        foreach (var item in lst)  
        {  
            COUNTRIES country = new COUNTRIES();  
            country.COUNTRY_ID = item.COUNTRY_ID;  
            country.COUNTRY_NAME = item.COUNTRY_NAME;  
            country.COUNTRY_CODE = item.COUNTRY_CODE;  
            lstRecord.Add(country);  

        }    
        return View(lstRecord);  
    }
```

**Web.Config**

[Web.Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmjKe.png)

**Project Overview**

Comment: Read [ask], include the actual error as text in your question, try searching for the error and show your research. This error has been discussed in hundreds of questions before.

Answer (score 0):

Describe what exactly the error you are getting, however There is no address provided in your WCF service endpoint configuration in webconfig. Please verify and include the address of your service endpoints.

```
<endpoint address="http://www.someaddress.com/someaddress" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the service element as:

```
<service name="BPP.CCSP.Admin.Services.AdminService" behaviorConfiguration="restbehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BPP.CCSP.Admin.Services.IAdminService"  />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```